Why wouldn't a DelegatingHandler execute on first request?
I'm working on a Blazor WebAssembly application and have created a DelegatingHandler called MyJWTHttpHandler to attach a JWT token to outgoing HTTP requests. However, I've encountered an issue where the handler does not execute on the first request until I refresh the page. After the refresh, the handler works as expected.
Here's the implementation of my handler:
public class MyJWTHttpHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly ISessionStorageService _sessionStorage;

    public MyJWTHttpHandler(ISessionStorageService sessionStorage) : base()
    {
        _sessionStorage = sessionStorage;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Sending Request");
            var token = await _sessionStorage.ReadEncryptedItemAsync<object>("Token");
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token?.ToString());
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine($"Error Sending Request: {ex.Message}");
            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}

And here’s how I’m registering the handler in Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddTransient<MyJWTHttpHandler>();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("BaseUrl", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<MyJWTHttpHandler>();


Hi @Hamza Modakir, could you pls also share your Program.cs file?

the section of code is representing code of my program.cs

Hi to everyone face this problem,
in my case i was working with Blazor Web App Auto that contains blazor web assembly and blazor server working together.
so i forget to register the handler in program.cs of the server
when i registered it solve the problem.
